# How to prune regrowth from a previously cut down tree?

Tags: trees, pruning

I have an [Albizia tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albizia_adianthifolia) with a very established root base that was recently cut down due to renovations. The existing stump (which was originally a regrowth as well I think) is only around 8cm across and about 1.5m high.

It has recently put out a large number of sprouts from top of the stump (all growing upward), they're about 20cm tall or so at the moment and growing rapidly.

I'd like to keep the tree but obviously if I just let it do what it wants it's going to end up being a bit of a strange looking tree.

I was hoping someone could give me some advise on how to choose which sprouts to take off and which and how many to keep. Should I just keep one that's around the middle of the stump and hope it branches out?

Answer (score 4):

I have observed and tended some regrowths from stumps over the years.  The first thing is to have patience and let the new sprouts grow for 1 or 2 years.  Then go and cut out one-third of the weaker sprouts and leave the stronger ones.  If there are several strong ones that are right next to each other take out all but the strongest of that grouping.  But still, leave 2/3 of the total the first year of pruning.  The next year cut out a half, and in the third year leave the strongest trunk and cut the rest.

This is a very conservative method, I have found that rushing this can cause the whole group to be shocked and die out.  You are trying to keep the roots alive so that a tree can establish itself.  I have left 3 to 5 trunk alive on an oak and a birch, and it is a magnificent group of trunks, and not advisable up near a house.

Answer (score 0):

I cut down two maple trees of different varieties on either side of my driveway. Now both of these stumps have produced a slue of "suckers" the tallest of which are now as tall as I. Now I am thinking I'll cut out most of these suckers be leave four or five of the tallest. Then next year cut several more out, leaving two or three of the tallest and strongest. The following I will save the tallest and strongest and cut the other one or two. This process will allow the root system to finally focus on one new growing tree.